# Check if cell contains all comma separated values

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a sheet with the following data:

```
| Text                                    | Value    |  Value   |  Value   |
|:----------------------------------------|:---------|:---------|:---------|
|Jax and Jax friend Kung Lao fight Raiden | jax      | kung lao | raiden   |
|Jax and Jax friend Kung Lao fight Raiden | kitana   | kung lao | raiden   |
```

And the following formulas:

```
=SUMPRODUCT( -- ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1:D1;A1)))=COUNTA(B1:D1)
=SUMPRODUCT( -- ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B2:D2;A2)))=COUNTA(B2:D2)
```

Which returns:

```
TRUE
FALSE
```

This is working as expected. I get **TRUE** of all values is found in the text-cell, and **FALSE** if one or all is missing.

Now, I want to modify so instead searching in multiple cells, I only want to search in one comma separated cell. Like this:

```
| Text                                    | Values                 | Formula |
|:----------------------------------------|:-----------------------|:--------|
|Jax and Jax friend Kung Lao fight Raiden | jax,kung lao,raiden    | TRUE    |
|Jax and Jax friend Kung Lao fight Raiden | kitana,kung lao,raiden | FALSE   |
```

I've tried with `=SUMPRODUCT( -- ISNUMBER(SEARCH({B2};A2)))=COUNTA({B2})` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting the comma delimited list and using the split array like a range of cells.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--isnumber(search(split(B2, ",", true, true), A2)))=counta(split(B2, ",", true, true))
'full word search
=SUMPRODUCT(--isnumber(search(text(split(B2, ",", true, true), " @ "), text(A2, " @ "))))=counta(split(B2, ",", true, true))
```

[image]

Comment: This do work, but I forgot to clarify that I only want to match on whole words. Getting **TRUE** for `kung la`, which should be **FALSE**

Comment: Wrap the text string in column A in spaces (e.g. " "&a2&" " as well as each piece of the split. See [edit] above.

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score 1):

Please see also:

`=AND(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXMATCH(A1,"(?i)"&SPLIT(B1,",")&"( |$)")))`

- `(?i)` - case insensitive
- `( |$)` - space or end of text, to match whole words only.

---

ArrayFormula variation for cell C1:

```
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(NOT(REGEXMATCH(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(filter(REGEXMATCH(A:A,"(?i)"&SPLIT(B:B,",")&"( |$)"),A:A<>"")),,10^99),"FALSE"))))
```